# Module @angular/core/index has no exported member "SimpleChanges"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to use ng2-bootstrap inside an Angular 2 application but am struggling with the basics. I have installed the package via NPM and am trying to load the Tabs solution. My component includes the lines

```
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {TAB_COMPONENTS} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

... and the minified JS file is referenced in my `index.html` file.

When I try and transpile using a gulp build I get the following error

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'
```

... but when I install angular forms the error reverts to

```
Module ... @angular/core/index has no exported member "SimpleChanges"
```

Can anybody please point a novice in the right direction.

Comment: What's the version of ng2?

Comment: Hi, The version installed via NPM is "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24".

Comment: That's the import for the `ng2-bootstrap` directive library, not `angular2`. I found an issue thread from the ng2 github site that sounds like it might help you out: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9247

Comment: thanks! The link has been very helpful. Still ironing out some issues but a big step forward starting with an upgrade to the RC version in my composer file.

Comment: Maybe it's a peer dependencies issue. What's the version of `@angular/forms` and `@angular/core`?